# ElasticSearch: how to define custom analyzers with REST API?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to define custom analyzers through the REST API (I'm using a hosted service - http://searchbox.io ), but I can't understand how to do it.

I'm trying to create a PUT request to /myindex/_settings with the following:

```
   index: {
            analysis: {
                    analyzer: {
                            "my_analyzer": {
                                    type: "snowball",
                                    language: "English"
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

but it doesn't work, if I index a field with "my_analyzer" set as the analyzer I'm getting an error that it doesn't exist..

Comment: after you've put the settings, what happens when you try to get them back using get settings api? /myindex/_settings ?

Comment: I see general index settings, nothing related to analysis and analyzers.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer - those settings must be set when creating the index.

so a POST request to /myindex did it.

Comment: Correct, otherwise you need to close the index before adding the analyzer and then reopen the index. Have a look [here](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Adding-analyzers-during-runtime-td3412592.html).

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?  Maybe post a small complete dictionary you were using to specify this?  I'm stuck at this point :-/